# How to create clipping masks on only some part of a text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I have a text layer and an abstract photo on top layer. And I want to create a clipping mask (insert the photo into the text). But the thing here is that I don't want the entire text to be clipped. Just some parts. For example I only want the "sample" from "this is a sample text" to be clipped by the abstract photo.

I tried duplicating the "sample" into another layer and then rasterizing it and then clipping the rasterized part but the text looks bold and outlines of the below text layer appear.

Also tried text selecting the "sample" with mouse and then clipping but guess that doesn't work in Ps.

Edit: Also what if I want the "sample" as well as "this" to be clipped?

Edit 2: In short how to create this effect given in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a layer mask on the image layer and black out the area that you don't want the texture to show?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are only 2 easy ways you can achieve this (I could be wrong):

1. You link the image to the text layer and resize it to fit only the "Battlefield" text.
2. You rasterize the text layer and using the rectangle tool select the part of the text, right click and choose `Layer Via Copy`, now you have a new layer with your specific text and link your image to only that layer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Hold Cmd and click on the text layer's thumbnail, your text will now be selected.

2) Use your marquee tool or lasso tool to deselect the text you do not want.

3) Apply masks or whatever you want to the remaining selection.

(no rasterization required)

Answer (score 0):

Be simple. Just duplicate the text layer, keep only the text you want for clipping and clip the image into this text layer. Nudge it to the top of the previous text layer and set it.

Comment: another answer already mentions that